# Xcode 7.3: NSArray print custom objects as "" why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, xcode7.3

I have array with custom type object when I tried to print it's shows me like array:

```
 (
    "",

    "",
 )
```

if I am accessing individual element it's show blank space even though printing property of element print correctly.why?

Updated:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[EventStore sharedEventStore] calendars]);

result - 2016-10-14 16:10:15.090 Sample[46141:431203] (

    "",

    ""



)
```

When I am iterating through it :

```
        for (Calendar *c in [[EventStore sharedEventStore] calendars]) {

            NSLog(@"Calendar - %@",c);

            NSLog(@"Calendar tille - %@",c.title);

            NSLog(@"Calendar color - %@",c.color);

        }
```

> 2016-10-14 16:04:48.879 Sample[52679:1434653] Calendar -
>
> 2016-10-14 16:04:56.221 Sample[52679:1434653] Calendar tille -
>   amanda@dev.com
>
> 2016-10-14 16:04:58.029 Sample[52679:1434653] Calendar color - (null)
>
> 2016-10-14 16:05:01.683 Sample[52679:1434653] Calendar -
>
> 2016-10-14 16:08:29.103 Sample[52679:1434653] Calendar tille -
>   Handball practice
>
> 2016-10-14 16:08:29.637 Sample[52679:1434653] Calendar color - (null)

Comment: you have array with two empty string so it is printing like this! what is wrong in it ?

Comment: show your custom objects and code for saving custom object  into array.Seems like you are saving custom objects in plist or in user Defaults which should be stored after archiving array data .

Comment: I have object of Calendar class object, printing individual prints <object returned empty description>.

Comment: calendars are coming from SDK method [[EventStore sharedEventStore] calendars] on event store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NSLog display of your class depends on your class's implementation of `description`. Your Calendar class has a `description` property whose value is an empty string.

Comment: will it effect anything with doing any operation using each element of array? Please, ans

Comment: It affects everything. Naming this property `description` was a really poor idea. This name is used by Cocoa. Give the property a different name.

Comment: so this class implement by other developer, what should I asked to do change? I am using their SDK.

Comment: Point them at the docs https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418746-description and show them their mistake, I guess...